# How to break a decimal value into integral and decimal portions

Tags: c#, asp.net, decimal-point

I'm currently working on a hotel management system's invoice (asp.net c#)... My question is that how to show the round off on a label example if the total amount is 8023.25 round off label should show .25 and totallabel should show 8023... 
Please can anybody help me with this {with code} ???

Comment: As @Lloyd has already said, please include a [minimal, complete and verifyable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and see the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split it and use them like:

```
string s = inputValue.ToString("8023.25", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string[] parts = s.Split('.'); 
int i1 = int.Parse(parts[0]);
int i2 = int.Parse(parts[1]);
```

Comment: but the second must be double, because he needs the number with the decimal point.

Comment: string value = total.Text;
        string a = value.ToString();
        string[] b = a.Split('.');
        int firstValue = int.Parse(b[0]);
        int secondValue = int.Parse(b[1]);

Answer (score 1):

You can do it mathematically:

- Get the integral part by casting it with `int`.
- To get the decimal portion, deduct the total amount with the intergral portion:

---

```
double amt = 8023.25;

int value = (int)amt;              //value will become 8023
double fraction = amt - value;     //fractionwill become 0.25
```